# JS vanila template of codesandbox not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, codesandbox

Attaching my code here. Trying to learn JS. Practicing my code in the codesandbox.io's vanilla JS template.

Error:

[image: This is the error I am getting]

It is not reading the function that I am defining.

CODE:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">   

<title>BOM property</title>
```

```
<h2>Browser Object Model (BOM) properties</h2>   

<script type="text/javascript">    

    function prpt()    

    {   

     document.write("The innerHeight is :"+window.innerHeight+"<br>"); //inner height   

     document.write("The innerWidth is :"+window.innerWidth); // inner width    

    }   

</script>      

<input type="button" value="innerHeight_Width" onclick="prpt()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to save the document with Ctrl + S keyword, and then execute the code.

Answer (score -1):

This code seems to work:

```html
<h2>Browser Object Model (BOM) properties</h2>   

<script type="text/javascript">    
    // fixed some space's
    function prpt() {   
      document.write("The innerHeight is :"+window.innerHeight+"<br>"); //inner height   
      document.write("The innerWidth is :"+window.innerWidth); // inner width    
    }   

</script>      

<input type="button" value="innerHeight_Width" onclick="prpt()">
```